# Find out network usage from router

Tags: router, statistics

I have a simple TP-LINK TL-WR841ND router and wanted to ask how can I find out the usage of the local network. I see there are received/sent Packets in wireless statistics, but am not sure what exactly this means. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values that you see are not going to be of much use to you. I have a similar router from the same manufacturer and they are simply a running total of the number of packets sent and received on the wireless channels since the device was turned on.

They're absolutely useless because they don't even include the number of transmit/receive errors that caused a packet to be resent (due to interference, poor signal, etc), they are not averaged per anything (per device, per minute/hour/day), etc.

The only purpose they can serve is to find out if *any* client *at all* is connecting to a certain channel. In my case, I have a dual-band router so I see both the 2.4GHz and the 5.0GHz channels, and if I had only 2.4GHz clients or only 5.0GHz clients, that would reflected in a total 0 packets sent/received for the other channel.

Like @juandeuax says, install an alternate firmware like OpenWRT and enjoy the benefits of real statistics such as bandwidth on WAN and LAN, packet failure statistics, client connections info, realtime bandwidth consumption, bandwidth by client, and more.

Comment: Will this affect the performance of the router, as the original firmware got an upgrade which improved it's performance which I want to keep

Comment: It won't use hardware NAT acceleration; I wouldn't recommend switching just for this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what form of usage data you want, but installing Gargoyle firmware on your router may well provide the features you're looking for.

Gargoyle is free to use and is listed as being [compatible with your router](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wr841nd). Simply put, Gargoyle replaces the user interface and provides much more [information and control features](https://www.gargoyle-router.com/wiki/doku.php?id=screenshots).

If you choose to try Gargoyle, make sure to follow the installation instructions to the letter since it is possible to brick (ruin) the router. I have been using Gargoyle on a TP-Link TL-WR1043ND for quite some time and I am very happy with it. It provides much more information/control, and I have had absolutely no problems with it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The original firmware already gives some kind of statistics, which I want to understand.